# Can i use same detailedViewController with different segue variables

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, segue

this is my problem. I can perfectly show a detailedViewController came from a table view, but i got 2 more tableview that i want to make it seem in detailed.When i gave it same variables - since every things that came same - it still doesn't go to the next view controller.I checked segue identifier aswell and i really don't want to make a new detailed controller.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        // Get destination view
        detailViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        destViewController.recipeName =[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
        destViewController.recipeDetail =[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeDetail"];
```

this is how i pass the data.They are exactly same with a small difference. The content of the content array.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. The segue identifier would be different of course. Therfore you would have to consider all the different segueIdentifiers in prepareForSegue.

Comment: BTW your detailViewController class should be named DetailViewController. Not related to your problem but conventions like this one help helping in forums like this.

Comment: @HermannKlecker ofc i changed the segue identifier as i mentioned in my explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. What is your problem? What exactly do you mean with "segue Variables"?

Comment: @HermannKlecker i want to use one detailedViewController with different segues.I got total of 3 tableview and each time user select a cell i want to go to the detailed view controller.Currently this detailed work with just one and i really don't wanna make the same viewController for 2 more times so i thought i should be able to use the same detailed view controller with different segueIndetifers and different contents

Comment: Yes, that is possible. For a start define the same view controller class name as the view controller class to each of the detail view controllers in the storyboard editor.

Comment: Done that already.@HermannKlecker

Comment: Have you set up a segue from each of your table view controllers to the same detail controller in the storyboard? If so, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the same view controller from multiple other controllers.  You may be able to do this by simply creating the segue from the appropriate cells in each table.  The way I've done it is to  create a segue from each table view controller to the "detail" view controller, and then perform the segue in code when the appropriate cell is selected.  Keep in mind that when creating segues in IB, there is a difference between creating them from table view cells and from the view controllers themselves.